Count unique individuals in each month
I have a dataframe that looks something like this:
data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
           species = c("species1","species1",
                       "species1","species1","species1","species2","species2",
                       "species2","species2","species2"),
              site = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
        first.date = c("01/01/2024","31/01/2024",
                       "02/02/2024","01/03/2024","05/04/2024","20/04/2024",
                       "05/05/2024","15/05/2024","05/06/2024","21/06/2024"),
         last.date = c("20/02/2024","02/02/2024",
                       "03/02/2024","15/03/2024","03/06/2024","10/05/2024",
                       "20/05/2024","20/05/2024","21/06/2024","21/06/2024")
)-> df

df

species site    first.date  last.date
species1    A   01/01/2024  20/02/2024
species1    B   31/01/2024  02/02/2024
species1    C   02/02/2024  03/02/2024
species1    D   01/03/2024  15/03/2024
species1    E   05/04/2024  03/06/2024
species2    A   20/04/2024  10/05/2024
species2    B   05/05/2024  20/05/2024
species2    C   15/05/2024  20/05/2024
species2    D   05/06/2024  21/06/2024
species2    E   21/06/2024  21/06/2024

I need a count for every month in which each species is present.
This should be output:
data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
           species = c("species1","species1",
                       "species1","species1","species1","species1","species2",
                       "species2","species2"),
             month = c("January","February","March",
                       "April","May","June","April","May","June"),
             count = c(2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L)
) -> per_month

per_month

species     month       count
species1    January     2
species1    February    3
species1    March       1
species1    April       1
species1    May         1
species1    June        1
species2    April       1
species2    May         3
species2    June        2

Can this be done using dplyr code?

See dplyr::n_distinct().

I think dplyr can do this combined with lubridate.
per_month <- mutate(df,month=month(floor_date(dmy(first.date),"month"),label=TRUE,abbr = FALSE)) %>% group_by(species,month) %>% count()

First, use mutate function to add a new column called month.
Then, use dmy(first.date) to convert the character to date formate.
Next, use floor_date（）function to get the month right.
Then, use month() to generate month label.
Then, use group_by to make groups.
Last, use count() to get the number.
